# Tossing $k$ biased coins

Tags: probability

I have a coin that comes up heads with very high probability $p$ and tails with probability $1-p$. Now, I take $k$ such coins and toss them all together.

What is the probability that the majority of coins in the toss show tails as a function of $k$? I have seen a result that states that this goes as $e^{-k}$ but I don't know how to prove it.

My attempt is here. The probability of getting a majority of coins to be tails is

$$P = \sum_{r = 0}^{k/2}{k\choose r}p^r(1-p)^{k-r}$$

How do I simplify this sum?

Comment: To be clear, the top limit of your summation should be $\lfloor{k/2}\rfloor$, in the case $k$ is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $k$ is sufficiently large and $p\gg 1/2$, then you can approximate the binomial distribution by a normal distribution, i.e. we have
\begin{align}
X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(p, k) \text{ can be normally approximated by } Y\sim  \mathcal{N}(kp, \sqrt{kp(1-p)})
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
P(X\leq \lfloor k/2\rfloor) \approx P(Y\leq (k+1)/2) = P\left(Z \leq z_0\right) 
\end{align}
where $z_0 = \frac{k(\frac{1}{2}-p)+\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{kp(1-p)}}$. Since $k$ is assume to be relatively large, then $z_0\approx -\sqrt{k}$

But, we know that
\begin{align}
P(Z\leq z_0 ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{z_0}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\ dx \lesssim   \int^{\infty}_k\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\ dx \lesssim \frac{e^{-k}}{\sqrt{k}}.
\end{align}